# Show that the matrix is invertible.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose $A$ be an $n×n$ real matrix be such that $A^k= O$ for some $k  \in \Bbb N$ then prove that $I+A$ is invertible.

Please do not use eigenvalues.

Answer (score 3):

$I-A^k = (I+A)(I - A...+(-1)^{k-1} A^{k-1}) = I$

$(I - A...+(-1)^{k-1} A^{k-1}) = (I+A)^{-1}$

Answer (score 2):

1 - A + A^2 - A^3 + ... (a finite sum)

Comment: Typo: first one should be an identity matrix, not a 1.